# How to print table (see image)

Tags: python-3.x

I am wondering if I can make a table like shown with nested loops:

```
 
    A   B   C   D
  +---+---+---+---+
1 |   |   |   |   |
  +---+---+---+---+
2 |   |   |   |   |
  +---+---+---+---+
3 |   |   |   |   |
  +---+---+---+---+
4 |   |   |   |   |
  +---+---+---+---+
```

This is my current code and results:

```
total_moves = 1
while total_moves <= 10:

    print('Turn {}'.format(total_moves))
        
    map = [ [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
            [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
            [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
            [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '] ]

    for i in map:
    
        print('\n' + '+---' * 4 + '+')

        for j in i:
        
            print('|{:^3}'.format(j), end = '')

        print('|', end = '')

    print('\n' + '+---' * 4 + '+')

chara = input('Please enter character to be added into box: ')
position = input('Please enter position where the character will be in: ')

Turn 1
+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
Please enter character to be added into box:
Please enter position where the character will be in:
```

I am having issues with printing the numbers and alphabets, because I am relatively new to nested loops. Tried doing `print(  A  B  C  D )`but am looking for a better way to print it. Thank you!

Comment: Why isn't `print(' A B C D ')` suiting your needs ?

Comment: Because I need the numbering as well, at the side. I don’t know how to implement that into the loop without compromising the boxes

Comment: I apologise if I phrased the question wrongly

Comment: Is the size of the grid fixed at 4x4 or can it change ?

Comment: It can be changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up so far:

```
total_moves = 1
while total_moves <= 10:

    print('Turn {}'.format(total_moves))

    map = [ [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
        [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
        [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
        [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '] ]

    columns = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P",\
"Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

    size = len(map)

    cols_string = ""

    for n in range(size):
        cols_string += " {}  ".format(columns[n])

    print(cols_string, end="")

    for idx, i in enumerate(map):

        print('\n  ' + '+---' * size + '+')
        print(idx + 1, end=" ")
        for j in i:
    
            print('|{:^3}'.format(j), end = '')

        print('|', end = '')

    print('\n  ' + '+---' * size + '+')
```

I added the `columns` list so that it can pick the column names depending on the size of the grid (assuming it won't be larger than 26x26).

Also added the `size` attribute so the display of the grid also adapts to the data.

I used `enumerate` to have the index of the line and print it in front of it.

One thing you'll have to figure out is how to properly display the `cols_string` because I didn't have the time to fix that.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will format `cols_string` myself, really appreciate the time you took to help!

Comment: Could you update me on how you fixed that ?

Comment: sure. 
i did `cols_string += "    {:2}".format(columns[n])` and `print("",cols_string, end="")`
essentially all i did was add "" infront of the print, and i do not think {:2} is necessassary ; but i did that as well

Comment: Alright thanks, I more used to using `f-strings` rather than `format()`.